# Issue after updating Dropwizard 0.9.3 to 1.3.12

Tags: java, dropwizard

Code worked fine with Dropwizard 0.9.3 with jdk1.8 but after updating to Dropwizard 1.3.12 getting the following issue.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   io.dropwizard.server.DefaultServerFactory.getJerseyRootPath()Ljava/lang/String;
>   at
>   io.federecio.dropwizard.swagger.ConfigurationHelper.getJerseyRootPath(ConfigurationHelper.java:53)
>   at
>   io.federecio.dropwizard.swagger.ConfigurationHelper.getSwaggerUriPath(ConfigurationHelper.java:84)
>   at
>   io.federecio.dropwizard.swagger.SwaggerBundle.run(SwaggerBundle.java:57)
>   at
>   io.federecio.dropwizard.swagger.SwaggerBundle.run(SwaggerBundle.java:37)
>   at io.dropwizard.setup.Bootstrap.run(Bootstrap.java:200) at
>   io.dropwizard.cli.EnvironmentCommand.run(EnvironmentCommand.java:42)
>   at io.dropwizard.cli.ConfiguredCommand.run(ConfiguredCommand.java:85)
>   at io.dropwizard.cli.Cli.run(Cli.java:75) at
>   io.dropwizard.Application.run(Application.java:79)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to upgrade `dropwizard-swagger`. See https://github.com/federecio/dropwizard-swagger/issues/93.